# Why the method innerHTML is making a change inside the html file, but it is not been displayed in the browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Why the method innerHTML is making a change inside the html file, but it is not been displayed in the browser? The idea is that when a user logged in, his name will be displayed in the header. I think that the problem is that header is loaded from the start, but I am making sure that the header is loaded before making any change. At the same time, the logout button is not working and I think that is for the very same issue.

**FILE: index.html**

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.9.0/firebase.js"></script>
        <script src="js/init.js"></script>
        <script src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function(){
                $("#header").load("header.html");
                $("#footer").load("footer.html");
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="header"></div>
        <div id="newsfeed"></div>
        <div id="footer"></div>

    </body>
</html>
```

**FILE: header.html**

```
 <header>
    <div class="generalHeader">
      <div class="header01">
         <a href="/index.html" id="wocTitle">WOC</a>
         <div class="loggedAs">
          Welcome,
          <a id="username"></a>!<br>
          <button id="logout_button">Log out.</button>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="header02">
        <ul class="menu" >
                <li><a class="active" href="">ALL</a></li>
                <li><a class="static">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp|&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</a></li>
                <li><a class="desactive" href="">RECOMMENDED</a></li>
                <li><a class="static">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp|&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</a></li>
                <li><a class="desactive" href="">SAVED</a></li>
                <li><a class="static"> &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp|&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</a></li>
                <li><a class="desactive" href="">POPULAR</a></li>
                <li><a class="static">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp|&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</a></li>
                <li><a class="desactive" href="">CATEGORIES</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
```

**FILE: index.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#header").load("header.html", function(){
  console.log("Header loaded.");

    // Set up UI elements
    var newsfeed = document.querySelector("#newsfeed"),
        username = document.querySelector("#username"),
        logout_button = document.querySelector("#logout_button");
    //Set user attributes
    var user_info, user_display_name;

    //Initialize Firebase
    var auth = firebase.auth(),
        storage = firebase.storage(),
        database = firebase.database();
    console.log("Firebase inizialized.");

    //Logout 
    logout_button.addEventListener('click', function(e){
      auth.signOut();
      console.log("You have been logged out");
      window.location = "index.html";
    });

    //Check user auth
    auth.onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
      //Get user full data
      user_info = user;
      if(user){
        console.log("User detected.");
        user_display_name = user_info.displayName;
        console.log("User display name read. User display name =", user_display_name);
        //Assign username to header
        username.innerHTML = user_display_name;
        console.log("username, ",username);

      }else{
        window.location = "login.html";
      }
    });

    //Get newsfeed
    //Listen from the latest 10 stories onwads, and display them
    database.ref("events").on('child_added', function(snapshot){
      displayEvent(snapshot.val());
    });


    //Listen to whenever a story changes
    database.ref("events").on('child_changed', function(snapshot){
      displayEvent(snapshot.val());
    });

    function displayEvent(value){
      console.log(value.imageUrl);
      storage.ref(value.imageUrl).getDownloadURL()
      .then(function(url) {
        $("#newsfeed").append("\<div class=\"event\"\>\<div class=\"event_title\"\>"+value.title+"\<\/div\>\<img class=\"event_image\" src=\""+url+"\"\/\>\<div class =event_header\>\<div class=\"event_info_header\" id=\"event_hour\"\>"+value.hour+"\<\/div\>\<div class=\"event_info_header\" id=\"event_date\"\>"+"   |   "+value.date+"   |   "+"\<\/div\>\<div class=\"event_info_header\" id=\"event_place\"\>"+value.place+"\<\/div\>\<\/div\>\<div class=\"event_brief_description\"\>"+value.brief_description+"\<\/div\>\<\/div\>");
        console.log("Event displayed");
      });
    }

  });
});
```

Comment: I think it's because in your `onAuthStateChanged` function, your variable `username` is undefined, since it's only in the scope of the `header.load()` function

Comment: But the change is been shown when the console.log("username, ", username) is been called.